How to exclude multiple values in SUMIF?
I need to exclude multiple values in a SUMIF statement. However, I need the "exclusion" list to be dynamic. I'm aware of how to list out all my exclusions.
Here is my current logic with one exclusion:
=SUM(SUMIFS(
Results!$I:$I,
Results!$B:$B,$A4,
Results!$P:$P,$C4,
Results!$Q:$Q,{"OFFSHORE"},
Results!$E:$E,{"<>Patch Testing"},
Results!$K:$K,$B4
))+P4

I need Results!$E:$E, to exclude a LIST of values from the "Task" tab for lines 6-100. Is this possible?  Thank you!

I think you can first sum everything without any exclusion:
=SUM(SUMIFS(
Results!$I:$I,
Results!$B:$B,$A4,
Results!$P:$P,$C4,
Results!$Q:$Q,{"OFFSHORE"},
Results!$K:$K,$B4
))

Then sum everything in your exclusion list:
=SUM(SUMIFS(
Results!$I:$I,
Results!$B:$B,$A4,
Results!$P:$P,$C4,
Results!$Q:$Q,{"OFFSHORE"},
Results!$E:$E,Task!A6:A100,
Results!$K:$K,$B4
))

Finally, subtract the two.

The second SUMIFS doesn't work.

Did you try to input it as an array formula? e.g by using crtl+shift+enter

That was it!! Thank you so much. I thought I did that originally.

Use SUM(FILTER()) instead:
=SUM(FILTER(Results!$I:$I,
    (Results!$B:$B=$A4)*
    (Results!$P:$P=$C4)*
    (ISNUMBER(MATCH(Results!$Q:$Q,{"OFFSHORE"},0)))*
    (ISERROR(MATCH(Results!$E:$E,Task!A6:A100,0)))*
    (Results!$K:$K=$B4))


Hi Scott, unfortunately, I don't have the filter function in my version of excel. Any other suggestions?
